# Numbers with leading zeroes, using vb6

Tags: vb6, number-formatting

How can I add leading zeroes to a number?
For example:

```
Dim stracctnumber as String
stracctnumber = 987654321
```

If `stracctnumber` is less than 15 characters, then add leading zeroes to the account number.

The final number should be

```
stracctnumber = "000000987654321"
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
stracctnumber = Format(stracctnumber, String(15, "0"))
```

Comment: Works for numeric `stracctnumber` only. `Right(..., 15)` works for any string.

Comment: @wqw - question is "How add leading zeroes to a **number**"

Comment: @MarkJ: Dont believe it! Read the code: `Dim stracctnumber as String`

Answer (score 5):

```
strAcct = Right("000000000000000" & strAcct, 15)
```

Note that concatenation is relatively 'expensive'. If this is just for display, rather than modifying the underlying value, consider using the `Format()` function.

Comment: the thing is the stracct may change. Sometimes it will like 10 somtimes it will 12 or 13 or 9

still it works?

Answer (score -1):

`B8 = Format((Format(B2, "###,###")), "@@@@@@@")`

This is to add spaces to left.

WORKS GREAT in VBA Excel.....